# EF 5 Model First - Table names are pluralized

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framewrok 5.0 Model First approach using Visual Studio 2012 express. The generated database tables are pluralized. How do I avoid this? Please advice.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2012 Professional you can do the following (I assume the same settings apply for express):

Tools Menu -> Options -> Database Tools -> O/R Designer - disable Pluralization of names

[image]

Comment: Generate database from model still uses pluralized names for some reason. so this did not help. I am using Model first